# print and download protected pdf viewer for web

Tags: javascript, php, pdf

i want to add viewer to web site.

the basic idea of the pdf viewer is show uploaded pdf files in the server to the client.

user cant print or download document.as a example for this kind of pdf viewer is slideshare.
it has no default option for download(slideshare people provide their custom button for do that)

Only users can be able to view document.

I tried several PHP,JavaScript plugins for doing that but unable to find one that has no print and downloadable options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Printing option is a built in browser option so you can't restrict it by any kind of plugins or scripts.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: thank you but currently my reputation is not allowing me to comment.

Answer (score 1):

You can Render the page empty in case of printing using CSS

```
@media print {  .no-print {display: none;  }}
```

and you should try to find an option to stop the control that views your PDFs from printing

Answer (score -1):

Basically, you have the Flash and Javascript solutions. While Flash technology is safer, it looks a bit obsolete and is avoided by some developers. Javascript, being a client-side technology, can only obfuscate the actual URL of the document or document content (pdf file).
For the Javascript side, the [pdf.js](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/) viewer is quite popular.